# Как сделать многократные замены?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Тут такая проблема:
Я написал функцию `replace`, чтобы она заменяла `[code]` на `<code>`.

Ну, появилась такая проблема: она заменяет только 1 элемент, а остальные не трогает.

Как сделать, чтобы она заменяла все?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь регулярным выражением с опцией g (global search).

```
"АБВАБВ".replace(/А/g, "_");
```

Comment: У меня указано оно вот так: "АБВАБВ".replace("[code]", "<code>");

Comment: Замените в методе строку регулярным выражением. Вот еще пример: http://www.wisdomweb.ru/JSd/strreplace.php

Перед [ и ] ставьте \  (специальные символы в регулярных выражениях: http://htmlweb.ru/java/regexp.php)

Comment: @Юра Спивак,

    console.log("АБВАБВ[code]ABC[code]DEF".replace("/\[code\]/", "<code>"));